# Qt - Arrange 40 labels according to their names

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have 40 labels, their layout arranged horizontally and their names are label_X
where X is an array of ascending numbers from 1 to 40

the problem is they are not arranged correctly according to their names in Qt-design
( for example their arrangement is like: **label_10**, **label_3**, **label_33**, ..., instead of **label_1**, **label_2**, **label_3**, ... )

Comment: Could you please be more precise. Did you use a layout? Did you arrange the labels with the help of the designer? If yes, did you check the ui XML-file?

Comment: yes I arranged them using qt designer .. what about XML-file ?

Comment: I do not understand the problem here. In the designer you can arrange the labels as you wish. Did you use a layout? In the XML-file (ui-file) you can clearly see the arrangement.

Comment: Just a tip: Use a horizontal layout and put the labels in it programmatically: Create them on the heap, give ownership to the widget that holds the layout and save the pointers in a container (e.g. vector). This is much more easy than arranging 40 labels by hand. If you do not need to change the labels afterwards, don't save the pointers.

Comment: Please provide more information. I cannot reproduce this either.

Comment: @Dominik Selzer, this help me alot

Comment: @Final Contest, sorry I'm still trying to make my questions more clear here.